# what is the best way to make a website doesn't require sign-up but i need to make log-in page for admin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web

I'm making a website like a blog, so website doesn't offer sign-up/in to the users, but i need to make log-in/out for the admin.
so what is the best way to do that,
should i make it just a link and every time admin want to login write the link
or what?

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: i'm very confused how to do it, it's my first project and i don't know what is the best way to do it

Comment: you can make a website and build an admin portal...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its really too broad. You have to **start** by going through references such as the official ASP.Net site - here's a link to [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) to get you _started_ - it will have links to more topics. There are no shortcuts to learning/understanding this.

Comment: @EdSF I think you don't understand my question,
i'm not asking about how to implement authentication and authorization,
i'm asking about where to but my log in link for admins only not for any one else in the site.

Comment: _"where to put my login link for admins and not for anyone else"_ **is authentication and authorization**. Again, go through the linked resources so you understand and do this the right way. If you already have this working and you're looking to "hide" some login link (a "secret link"), then you'll have to share that link and hope that nobody shares it. A website can distinguish anonymous or not by going through some _authentication_ process (aka "login")